# Функция определения простоты числа на JS

Tags: javascript

Функция определяет число простое или нет. Если вызвать функцию в консоль лог, результат корректный, если перебирать числа от 0 до некоторого в цикле фор, некоторые числа выдают не корректное значение, не вижу где ошибся.

```js
let i = 3; //Старт для перебора функции симпл
let lim = 25; //лимит до которого выводть последовательность простых чисел

function simple(x) { //Функция определения простоты числа
    if (x == 1) {
        return false;
    };
    if (x == 2) {
        return true;
    };

    if (x % 2 == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    while (i * i <= x) {
        if (x % i == 0) {
            return false;
        } else (i++);
    };
    return true;
};

 console.log(simple(15)); //Проверяем что 15 точно фолс вне перебора ниже

 for (q = 0; q < lim; q++) {
    if (simple(q) == true) {
        console.log(q); //Перебор доходит до 15 и выдает тру
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Следует поменять `let i = 3; //Старт для перебора функции симпл` на `var i = 3; //Старт для перебора функции симпл` и перенести в тело функции `simple`. Иначе i не переопределяется с прошлых циклов проверки.

```js
let lim = 25; //лимит до которого выводть последовательность простых чисел

function simple(x) { //Функция определения простоты числа

    var i = 3; //Старт для перебора функции симпл
    
    if (x == 1) {
        return false;
    };
    if (x == 2) {
        return true;
    };

    if (x % 2 == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    while (i * i <= x) {
        if (x % i == 0) {
            return false;
        } else (i++);
    };
    return true;
};

 console.log(simple(15)); //Проверяем что 15 точно фолс вне перебора ниже

 for (q = 0; q < lim; q++) {
    if (simple(q) == true) {
        console.log(q); //Перебор доходит до 15 и выдает тру
    };
};
```

Comment: `let` на `var` можно не менять

Comment: @Grundy, ок. Принял к сведению.

Comment: Не учел что не переопределяется, благодар.